# fetch value from JQuery to ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, session-cookies

I'm converting the value below "100 MYR" to different country currency. The converter is using JQuery (Google API). I wanted to pass the value(converted currency) to a label(lblAmountPaid) in another page below. I tried using session and cookies method but couldn't work, it returns empty string. Please help, thank you.

[image]

**ccGOOG.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#submit').click(function () {
    var errormsg = "";
    var amount = $('#txtAmount').val();
    var from = $('#drpFrom').val();
    var to = $('#drpTo').val();
    $.ajax({ type: "POST",
        url: "WebService.asmx/ConvertGOOG",
        data: "{amount:" + amount + ",fromCurrency:'" + from + "',toCurrency:'" + to + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#results').html("Converting...");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#results').html(amount + ' ' + from + '=' + data.d.toFixed(2) + ' ' + to);
        },

        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                errormsg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.'; ;
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                errormsg = 'Requested page not found. [404]'; ;
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                errormsg = 'Internal Server Error [500].'; ;
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                errormsg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.'; ;
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                errormsg = 'Time out error.'; ;
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                errormsg = 'Ajax request aborted.'; ;
            } else {
                errormsg = 'Uncaught Error.';
            }
            $('#results').html(errormsg);
            $('<a href="#" >Click here for more details</a>').click(function () {
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            }).appendTo('#results');
        }
    });
});
});
```

Below is another page :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you call an ASP.NET AJAX Page Method in your `success` callback of the `.ajax()` method, like this:

First, here is the page method with `Session` enabled:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static void SetAmountInSession(int amount)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["amount"] = amount;
}
```

Next, you need to call this from the `success` callback of the jQuery `.ajax()` method, passing it the result of the Google API call, like this:

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#results').html(amount + ' ' + from + '=' + data.d.toFixed(2) + ' ' + to);
    var args = {
        amount: data.d.toFixed(2)
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "YourPage.aspx/SetSession",
        data: JSON.stringify(args),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () {
            alert('Success.');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Fail");
        }
    });
},
```

Finally, in your "other" page, you can grab the value in `Session`, like this:

```
// Check if value exists before we try to use it
if(Session["amount"] != null)
{
    lblTotalAmount.Text = Session["amount"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I followed everything, when i clicked the convert button it displays a messagebox saying "Fail" and no value in return in the other page. I don't understand why.